# Reopen question on Devil negation

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[Syntax of 'f*** off has he', 'b******* do they', and the like](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4486/syntax-of-f-off-has-he-b-do-they-and-the-like) was closed with the rationale:

> "Language-specific grammar and usage questions are off-topic unless primarily concerned with linguistics rather than usage. There are many language-specific sites where such questions are welcomed; see: http://stackexchange.com/sites" – bytebuster, Otavio Macedo

The querent was only aware of the construction occurring in British English. But as it turns out, Devil negation occurs in a large number of languages, including Modern Greek (which I've written a paper on), Irish, and Cantonese. So the reason given for closing the question was, I believe, not valid: just because the question was *illustrated* with British English, does not mean the question is restricted in scope to British English. (And in any case, the question was about how the construction is linguistically analysed; again, "primary concerned with linguistics".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid points. I have reopened this question.